# Replacing failed disk with Dlink DNS-320 NAS

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid, nas, raid-1

I have a NAS (Dlink DNS-320) and one of my 2 RAID1 disks failed (showing amber color).

[image]
I bought a new HDD (same mark Seagate, same size 2T). After replacing the failed disk, no more amber led and the management interface, connects to 
"Hard drive configuration section".

[image]

[image]

- Step1: The new hard drive is properly detected (correct SN).

## Issue

- Step2: In the second step of the wizard, only  **standard** type is shown, NOT what I need. According to the help, I need the option **"Format the new hard drive as RAID1"**
  ==> If I continue with **"standard"** I will have two separate volume. It is not what I want.

So, leds shows the remaining disk is OK, but no sign of it in the configuration only the new one is showed. Theoretically RAID1 should be downgraded and I should have seen the remaining disk as simple volume, but it shown nowhere.

Is there something wrong?

In Disk management > S.M.A.R.T test only one (the new) disk is detected?
[image]

Eventhough, all the time the led showing that the left disk is intact, in the configuration management, no sign of the disk:

[image]

Any hint?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should go to the configuration of the existing (degraded) RAID 1.  Your option should be in there.

Comment: Thanks @Damon for your reply. There is no place where "Downgraded" state of RAID1 is shown. According to the doc, I should have the option "Format the new hard drive as RAID1" in the wizard when I insert a new disk. Besides there is no sign of the left (intact) disk in the configuration as I showed in the additional picture.

Comment: If you have access to the existing data, then you have access to configure that existing array somewhere.  I'm not saying you will have many options, but if you had any, those would be the ones you are looking for.  None of your screen shots show an existing array at all.  Formatting the new drive as a new RAID 1 is kind of irrelevant to your issue.   What you need to find is how to configure the existing array.  The procure is very simple.  Executing the procedure through your GUI is the [ultimate] complexity.  This is a snap from the command line on Linux.  Your GUI probably runs on Linux.